# trying to make a mouse rotation script in unity, but it does nothing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a 3d platformer In unity as my first game, and I'm trying to add some mouse rotation, but don't know what to do. the problem is it literally will not rotate.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PCM : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 10.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translation = Input.GetAxis("MouseX") * speed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("MouseY") * speed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;  
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translation);
    }
}
```

[all player propeties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNb9.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give more information, such as what it is that you're trying to rotate and in what way is it not working, what kind of game you're making (2d topdown, 2d platformer, 3rd person, FPS) etc.

Comment: Please show your key binds for Horizontal and Vertical, and please show your camera transform and hierarchy.

Comment: @Immersive Done!

Answer (score 0):

I assume, since you said "platform" that you're doing 2D.  You had

```
transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translation);
```

Usually, 2D works on X- (left/right) and Y- (up/down) axes (and Z is "in/out").  Try

```
transform.Translate(straffe, translation, 0);
```

Comment: nah, im doin 3d